# PHP and javascript working correctly on Internet Explorer and Google Chrome but not on Samsung Galaxy Android

Tags: php, javascript, android, format

I have a php based web app that on a user entering a value, it pulls the details from the mysql database and displays it without the page being refreshed. This is obviously done with javascript.

This works 100% correctly on internet explorer, chrome etc. from mobile devices such as blackberries and tablets the formatting is messed up once the user enters data. see screen shots below.

Internet explorer, table structure remains in tacts:
[image]

Mobile Device (Galaxy Tablet), table structure is changed:
[image]

[example can be viewed here](http://www.unilever-sales.co.za/newsaletest2.php)

The Code for the 2 pages involved is shown below. the front end is a php page which used javascript to fetch and display data from mysql.

php page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function showUser(userNumber, str) 
  { 
  document.getElementById("r"+(userNumber)).style.display="block";  
    if (str=="") 
    { 
      document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML=""; 
      return; 
    }   
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    else 
    {// code for IE6, IE5 
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    } 

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
    { 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
      { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
      } 
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true); 
    xmlhttp.send(); 
  } 
</script> 
</head>
<body>

<form name="orderform" id="orderform" action="newsale.php" method="post">

<div align="left" id="txtHint1">mysql data will be shown here</div>
<br>
<table border="1">

    <tr id="r1">  
        <td>
            <input size="8"  type="text" id="sku1" name="sku1" onchange="showUser(1, this.value)" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input  type="text" id="qty1" name="qty1" size="3">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="r2">  
        <td>
            <input size="8"  type="text" id="sku2" name="sku2" onchange="showUser(1, this.value)" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input  type="text" id="qty2" name="qty2" size="3" >
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

getdata1.php page to fetch mysql data:

```
<?php
 $q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
 if (!$con)
   {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$sql="SELECT Category, Description,SellingUnits,Grouping,CasesPerPallet,ShrinksPerPallet FROM skudata WHERE packcode = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<font color=blue size=2>Description:</font> <font color=red size=2>".$row['Description']."</font>, ";
   }

mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Thanks again for all the asistance, it is appreciated.

Alternatively, does anybody have another javascript they can give me to dispaly the data from mysql? apologies but my javascript skills are non existant.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Please show the generated HTML (right click -> view source) - It looks like you have an unclosed tag somewhere, although it's not leaping out at me. Also, please pick a doctype and stick to it, properly. **All** attribute values should be enclosed in quotes. `<font>` tags should be avoided - use CSS instead.

Comment: use standard html 1.0 strict or html5 and use the validator to validate it http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: I still can't find that unclosed tag that I'm sure is there, it's very hard to read your HTML. The first thing you need to do is add quotes around all your attribute values - it's possible the problem is being cause by the empty, unquoted `value=` attributes in the `<input>`s, like `value= >`. You are certainly giving the HTML parser a difficult job and I'm not surprised you're getting errors. Add a `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the very first line of the document, and go through and add quotes, so (e.g.) `<font color=grey>` becomes `<font color="grey">`.

Comment: Hi @DaveRandom, Thanks again for the help and your time. I have updated the questions to show a simplified version of the code, with only the functionality I am looking for, same result. Hopefully I have formatted the code correctly. Thanks, Ryan

Comment: @RyanSmith do as dave suggests and put a DOCTYPE in your document, else your browsers will be entering various default 'Quirks modes'. Depending on what DOCTYPE you use, some markup may need to change, such as your single tag items <input> etc. will need to change to <input />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the first line of your JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("r"+(userNumber)).style.display="block";
```

You're setting the display style of the first table row to `block`. I don't think there's a reason to do that in your case, so just remove the line and your HTML will work nicely in all browsers, including the Samsung Galaxy Tab (I tested this on an actual tablet).

As a side note, the cell shifting effect also happened in FireFox (and not anymore).

Comment: Thanks Alex, 100%. thanks to everyone for the time and effort you put into idiots like me :-)